# Is the set of linear transformations $\mathcal{L}(V, \mathbb{F})$ guaranteed to contain at least one injective transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, proof-writing, linear-transformations

I was wondering if there's a quick answer to this question, preferably with a supporting proof or argument. Just quickly thinking of the extreme case where $V = \{ \mathbf{0} \}$, it is true that any linear transformation $T: \{ \mathbf{0} \} \to \mathbb{F}$ is injective because there is only one element in the preimage.

In summary, I'm after an argument for/against the idea that every set of linear transformations from a vector space $V$ to a field $\mathbb{F}$ ($\mathcal{L}(V, \mathbb{F}) = V^*$ if you prefer) contains at least one injective transformation.

Cheers!

Comment: Have you tried to see what happens in an actual example, like $V=\mathbb R^2$?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez I've thought about it but it's hard to inspect the set of **all** linear transformations from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}$...

Comment: @TristanBatchler The set of all linear transformations from $\mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}^n$ can be viewed as the set of $n \times m$ matrices.

Comment: Any linear transformation from the plane to the line looks like $f(x, y) = ax + by$ for some constants $a, b$. Can you find two different points mapping to $0$?

Comment: Well $f(0, 0) = 0$ and I suppose so does $f(-by/a, y)$ assuming $a \neq 0$.

Comment: I find it very surprising that you know what the dual space of a vector space is or what the dimension of a vector space is, and find it hard to inspect all linear transformations $\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R$ :-|

Comment: @TristanBatchler: Yep, and also $f(bt, -at) = 0$ for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$, with no assumptions on the values of $a$ and $b$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $T : V \to \mathbb{F}$ is injective, then the dimension of the image $T(V)$ is $\dim(V)$. However, the image lies in the one-dimensional vector space $\mathbb{F}$ so if $\dim(V) > 1$ this is a contradiction.

Comment: So basically this is only true for $V$ is the zero vector space or $\mathbb{F}$?

Comment: Yes, or any isomorphic copies of $\{0\}$ or $\mathbb{F}$, obviously.